# change masterpage image src from page in update panel C#

Tags: c#, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a master page that contains an image as follow:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCompanyLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="image path" />
```

and in a child page I want to edit the property `ImageUrl` as follow:

```
Image imgCompanyLogo = (Image)Page.Master.FindControl("imgCompanyLogo");
imgCompanyLogo.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/CompanyLogo/Logo.png");
```

and it doesn't give me an exception, but it doesn't change anything.

Note: I have an `UpdatePanel` in the child page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is sitting outside of the UpdatePanel, server side changes will not be executed on the image after a partial postback.  Your only option is to inject JavaScript into the page and change the image URL.

Use the [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) to inject JavaScript after the partial postback.

Something like the following will work for you:

**C#**

```
protected void btnPostback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgCompanyLogo.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/CompanyLogo/Logo.png");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnPostback,this.GetType(), "myScript", "ChangeImage('" + ImageUrl + "');",false);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ChangeImage(imgURL) {
    //make sure the ID of the image is set correctly
    document.getElementById('imgCompanyLogo').src = imgURL; 
}
```

Comment: Upvote: but what i really do is that i have javascript end request handler and frome it a call javascript function on master page, because the image is runat server so you cant edit it from child page :)

Comment: That will work also.  As long as JavaScript is being executed in some fashion then you'll be able to change the image src.  Is that what you've done so far?  Is it working for you?

Comment: ya it works, but is there another way to do it? thanks in advanced

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it but this is one of the quickest and most direct method.

Comment: plz give me hints, i really want to know :)

Comment: Executing JavaScript on the client is certainly going to be the fast way. Why do you want to do it another way?

Comment: @Hiyasat: There have been several good methods presented as answers to this question.  What is missing for you?

Comment: i know it is fast, all other methods almost the same way except @HalfTrackMindMan and it not really that efficiency if you have more than one control to change as in my case. and for me i just want to know as you mentioned there are other ways, note +1

Answer (score 1):

Wrap image by UpdatePanel with UpdateMode="Always"

Master Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

public void SetImageUrl(string url)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = url;
}
```

Child Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="Click Me" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateImage" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
    protected void UpdateImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Main)Master).SetImageUrl("~/Images/0306d95.jpg");
    }
```

The code above works well for me.

Comment: The image is sitting outside of the UpdatePanel.  Changing the UpdateMode won't affect anything that isn't inside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: I don't mean to change UpdateMode of the panel on the child page, bu instead add another panel onto the MasterPage and place image into it.

Comment: and in my case i also have link style sheet i want to change, so it is not efficiency

Answer (score 0):

If your code is being run after an async postback (per your `UpdatePanel`) then changes to anything outside the `UpdatePanel` will not be rendered. Content in the master page would definitely seem to qualify.

If this is what you're trying to do, this model won't really work. You will need to use some client script to effect changes to already-rendered content when working with this model.

An `UpdatePanel` is a construct to identify an area that's updated through ajax. The page is not actually reloaded. So an postback can never change content that's outside of the `UpdatePanel` (or control bound to that panel) that sourced it.

Here's a basic implementation (using jQuery). Add a hidden field to pass the new source to the client. This *must* be inside the `UpdatePanel`. Change this value from the server when you want the image to update with `new_image_src.Value=ResolveUrl(...);`

```
<asp:HiddenField ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server" id="new_image_src" 
    value="" EnableViewState="false">
```

Give your image a static id too to make life easier:

```
<asp:Image ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server" id="dynamic_image" ImageUrl="..." >
```

Add javascript to the page (should NOT be in the UpdatePanel):

```
function updateImage() {
    var new_src=$('#new_image_src');
    if (new_src) {
        $('#dynamic_image').attr('src',new_src);
        /// erase it - so it won't try to update on subsequent refreshes
        new_src.val('');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// adds an event handler after page is refreshed from asp.net
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(updateImage);
});
```

This wouldn't be difficult to do without jquery either but seems more common than not these days.

Comment: thanks, bit that was i did as @Alison almost recommend, but can you give me another way :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` Class. Define handler in javascript and may change the image source.